# pandas iterrows index seems wrong(misunderstanding!)

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I found this weird problem I could not get my head around (hate pandas). I have a dataframe `df` with shape: `(1033, 5)`. So, my understanding is that there are 1033 rows and 5 columns.

Now I iterate through this using:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx)
```

In this loop I see numbers greater than 1033 such as 1722.. WTF is going on? Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Probably the index is not a normal range, and some values are missing

Comment: Check with `(pd.RangeIndex(df.shape[0])==df.index).all()`

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'` for that

Comment: Well then, df.index.max()

Comment: yes. it is giving me 1722 :( WTF is this? :( How do I refer to this row in pandas now? :(

Comment: No worries :) reset the index, `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: can you please tell me when I need to aware of this? why is the index this way? this seems like a nasty gotcha

Comment: Nah this is probably that you've dropped some rows, reindexed at some point etc. Keeping the original index can be useful in some cases

Comment: ah ok. Thanks. one more Q: what is `drop=True` do? Please post this as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Nah this is a clear dupe. That just drops the original index, otherwise it adds it as column

Comment: ah Ok - I could find a post for it. Anyways. Thanks a tonne.

Comment: No problem, will set as a reset_index dupe

Comment: This index is not the regular index as you would imagine in a loop, it is the index position of that data in the dataframe